# How to plot Stacked columns and clustered columns on the same graph using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

I want to display stacked columns along with the clustered columns on the single graph using dojo 1.9. see the below ref[image]

Any help?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: hello everyone.I have the same problem.I struggling from last 1 month to create this type of chart using dojo 1.9.so suggest us anyone how can we create combine stacked clustered chart

Comment: ..are you solved this problem.